# Twilio Flutter dependencies are not working

Tags: flutter

Hi my `Twilio Flutter` dependencies are not working please help me

**code**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pubspec.yaml` looks like the following. The error occurs because of your `http` dependency is incorrectly indented.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    http: ^0.12.1
  twilio: ^0.0.5
```

Your dependencies should look like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.1
  twilio: ^0.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be very about indentation in pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.1
  twilio: ^0.0.5
```

add dependencies after 2 space. in http package you had 3 or more space.